# Select column 2 to last column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with multiple columns. Now, I want to get rid of the row.names column (column 1), and thus I try to select all the other columns.

E.g.,

```
newdata <- olddata[,2:10]
```

is there a default symbol for the last column so I don't have to count all the columns?
I tried

```
newdata <- olddata[,2:]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: `olddata[, 2:ncol(olddata)]` (or) `olddata[, -1, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @Arun: `ncol(olddata)`, not `ncol(newdata)`

Comment: Rcoster, yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Just to be clear, you have a column named `row.names`?  Or you want to drop the row names?  (Row names are not a column.)

Comment: @ Matthew Lundberg: Yes, I read in a csv table that has names in the first column, and I want to get rid of it so I can transform the data frame into a matrix

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think it's better to focus on *wanting to get rid of one column of data* and not wanting to select every other column. You can do this as @Arun suggested:

```
olddata[,-1]
```

Or:

```
olddata$ColNameToDelete <- NULL
```

Comment: `olddata$ColNameToDelete <- NULL` makes more sense.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, it makes more sense when you're dropping it from the existing `data.frame`, but not in the sense that the OP has presented their problem.

Comment: olddata[,-1] is even better, since shorter. Thanks, for all the quick suggestions!

Comment: @SeñorO, If your `data.frame` has only 2 columns, then this will result in a vector unless you use `drop = FALSE`.

Comment: I think he was referring to the fact that I had `RowNameToDelete` instead of `ColNameToDelete` before I edited it

Answer (score 15):

You can get the last column with `ncol()`:

```
 newdata <- olddata[,2:ncol(olddata)]
```

Answer (score 5):

To build on Freeman's answer, Tidyverse allows dots as replacement for the piped data object, which can be useful to simplify code with repetitive references to the object.

`library(tidyverse)`

`newdata <- olddata %>% select( 2:ncol(.) )`

or

`newdata <- olddata %>% .[,2:ncol(.)]`

Answer (score 0):

I am using this selecting all columns without one or more columns from the beginning:

```
newdata = olddata[ , 2:dim(olddata)[2]] # from column 2 to the last one (the original question)
```

```
newdata = olddata[ , 5:dim(olddata)[2]] # from column 5 to the last one (example of more columns)
```