# How to select last x numbers of column in a data frame without referencing to the column numbers?

Tags: r

I am looking for a simple R code to say, precisely, select the last 3 columns in a data frame. I don't want to refer any other column numbers (e.g. "select  from *2nd* to the last column") because the number of columns I add to the end of my data frame keeps changing.  An identical question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28017141/select-the-last-n-columns-of-data-frame-in-r) but the answers were to the specific problem of the user not to the actual question in the title. There's another entry with a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326792/select-column-2-to-last-column-in-r), but the user asked to select "column n to the last column", which is not what I want.

```
x1 = rep("A", 5)
x2 = rep("B", 5)
x3 = c(1:5)
x4 = c(36:40)

dat = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
dat
dat[, 2:(ncol(dat))] #First option, not what I want
dat[,(ncol(dat)-2):ncol(dat)] #Second option, again not there yet...
```

The two solutions I can think of give me the correct output but both select from "column number n to the last one".

All I want to say: give me the last three columns in a data frame. That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `tail`

```
n <- 3
dat[tail(seq_along(dat),n)]
```

Comment: Sorry for the follow up, but do you know, by any chance, why this is not working: `names(dat[tail(seq_along(dat),3)])<-c(paste(c(rep("newname",3)),c(1:3),sep=""))`. Basically I am trying to change the names of the last three columns in the data frame. But it doesn't work?

Comment: @Eva If you need to change the column names, `names(dat)[tail(seq_along(dat), n)] <-  paste0('newname', tail(colnames(dat), n))`